# Tratar intervalos entre dois campos Time Mysql

Tags: mysql, time

Tenho uma tabela `Atendimento` no meu BD. Dentro dela tenho dois campos que são: `HrIni` que refere-se a hora inicial e outro `HrFim` que refere-se a hora final.

Eu preciso que para cada registro destes dois campos seja armazenado em um novo campo `tempo` o valor **SIM** para atendimentos que duraram **mais de 20 min.**; e o valor **NAO** para atendimentos que duraram   **menos de 20 min**. 
No caso eu teria que fazer o cálculo do intervalo enter HrIni e HrFim (Formato - 00:00:00).

Alguém pode me ajudar? Caso não tenha sido claro peço que me informem.

Comment: Preciso armazenar, pois vou usar os dados que serão exportados em outro formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `TIMEDIFF()`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001','2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002')
```

Fonte: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Não sei qual a linguagem que você está usando, mas em PHP eu faria assim:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("exemplo.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Verifica conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, TIMEDIFF(HrIni,HrFim) AS diferenca FROM Atendimento");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$sim_nao = ($row["diferenca"] > 20) ? 'SIM' : 'NAO';

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Atendimento SET tempo='".$sim_nao."' WHERE id='" . $row['id'] ."'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Não teria algo mais específico para realização desta alteração para me mostrar?

Comment: Você pode usar a função para retornar a diferença e tratar ela em código. Aí adicionar na tabela tempo de acordo com a diferença. Por exemplo faz um `SELECT TIMEDIFF(HrIni,HrFim) AS diferenca FROM Atendimento`.

Comment: Não conseguiria expor algo mais completo, como por exemplo, o código postado por @Rubico acima?

Comment: Editei a resposta, não sei qual a linguagem que você usa, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: Consegui. Muito Obrigado. Foi útil sua resposta e a utilizei. Depois criei outro campo para receber 'Maior que 20' quando Tempo>=00:20:00 e a mesma coisa para quando menor.

Answer (score 2):

Rodrigo,

acho que uma [Trigger](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3567/mysql-basico-triggers.aspx) atenderia a sua necessidade.
Nunca criei uma, mas a ideia da trigger é a seguinte, após um INSERT, DELETE ou UPDATE a trigger é disparada e o código pertencente a trigger é executado. Dê uma lida sobre triggers.

Editado:

De uma forma bem grossa, a criação da sua trigger ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nome_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON nome_tabela
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    #SEU CODIGO VEM AQUI, ALGO COMO:
    IF NEW.hrIni IS NOT NULL AND NEW.hrFim IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF TIMEDIFF(NEW.hrFim, NEW.hrIni) > 20 THEN
            NEW.tempo = 'SIM'
        ELSE
            NEW.tempo = 'NAO'
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Este com trigger encontra-se dando erro de sintaxe.